# No Button Feedback In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, feedback

no button feedback in android studio, i just want to guide from one activity to another! :(

no errors
here's the code

```
public abstract class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  
    private Button clickButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        clickButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.IDbutton2);
       

        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivity();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(OrderActivity.this, orderPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

using nexus 6 emulator

please help guys

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set a content view, so your `OrderActivity` has no layout. As such, there is no view with ID `IDbutton2`. This causes `clickButton` to be null, and not do anything.

You can see a very similar example [in the Android training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent) (I've removed the irrelevant bits):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```